# Adding attribute to iframe's body works in Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, iframe, document

Does anyone know why this works - that is to say, the attribute is added - in Chrome, but not in Firefox?

```
this.wrapper.appendChild(this.ifr = document.createElement('iframe'));
this.ifr_doc = this.ifr.contentDocument || this.ifr.document;
this.ifr_doc.documentElement.querySelector('body').setAttribute('foo', 'bar'); //GRR...
```

No error; it's just in Chrome, in the inspector, the attribute shows up, while in Firefox (v 41.0.2) it doesn't.

(`this.wrapper` is a container housing the iframe)

Comment: check your `this.ifr_doc.documentElement.querySelector('body')` element, is it definied in ff?

Comment: Yeah I checked, it is.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
 if (this.ifr_doc.readyState == 'complete') {      
     this.ifr_doc.body.setAttribute('foo', 'bar'); 
 }
```

Comment: Interesting - the document always comes back as uninitialised, even if I check again later via a timeout. How do I initialise it, then? +1.

Comment: From reading MDN I do not - cannot - manually initialise it - it's initialised only once the readystatechange or domcontentloaded event fires. Since I'm creating a new iframe and document afresh, I'm not sure what I can do here, then. Perhaps I should post this up as a separate question.